# If a variable is assigned an object returned by a function, is it copied or created in-place?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, return-value-optimization, nrvo

I have something like this in my CPP file to initialize an object outside any class. I've simplified it but the point is there is some complex initialization going on but I want a single instance created:

```
static MyBigObject o = []()
{
  MyBigObject ret;
  ret.Init();
  return ret; 
}();
```

My question is, does this object get copied from `ret` to `o` or created in-place due to compiler cleverness? There might be a proper term for "created in place" - emplaced?

I am working in C++17, if it's pertinent (i.e. the answer depends on language version). Is there a definite answer, or could this be a compiler-specific optimisation?

Comment: In short: almost certainly optimized. In long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: FWIW, since C++11, if the operation is not  elided, then the returned value will be moved if there is a move constructor.

Comment: *created in-place due to compiler cleverness?* -- If the compiler is clever enough to do it, it will do it.  Why would it waste the opportunity?  Also, C++ compilers from way back even before standardization in 1998 did all sorts of tricks to optimize and outdo competing C++ compilers.

Comment: It depends on what operations (move constructors, etc) `MyBigObject` supports.   But, in this case, the problem can be eliminated by having the default constructor of `MyBigObject` do all the "complex initialization" needed, rather than waiting for a member function `Init()` to be called after the constructor completes.   Then the definition of the instance can simply be `MyBigObject o;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case: this depends on your compiler. This is [named return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is optionally elided. C++17 allows, but not requires, the copy to be elided even if the object has observable side effects in its copy/move constructors (and its destructor).

Comment: There's a word I never new existed!